# Can I animate a view and every other view that attached to/ has constraints relation with it?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to animate a specific view that also has another view (used for shadow effect) attached to it? I'm using constraintlayout.
But only the main view moved and not both

Comment: You can use ConstraintSet to animate your elements in constraintlayout. There are lot of articles with examples with constraint animations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group all of the views you want to animate into a single ViewGroup i.e. a FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, whatever suits best. You can then apply your animation to this ViewGroup and all of its children will move with it.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that this one solution. But I wanted to know if I can animate both of them with out being contained inside one view.